# Feedback Mechanism / Learning for Relationship Extraction

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, relationship-extraction

Is there a feedback mechanism that allows us to correct mistakes made by  Relationship Extraction so that it becomes smarter overtime and doesn't make the same mistake? e.g. if it doesn't identify the name of someone as a PERSON or perhaps it is unable to identify something as an ORGANIZATION.

Comment: Can you give more of the specifics on what you are trying to do? It helps if you can give a code example of what you have already tried.

Comment: Sorry I haven't actually coded anything yet, I have just merely ran the example provided when you install the kit and also parsed news articles in the online demo.

Answer (score 0):

There is no feedback mechanism for Relationship Extraction. If you are trying to recognize a well known `PERSON` or `ORGANIZATION` then I would suggest you to use the [Alchemy Language](http://www.alchemyapi.com/products/demo/alchemylanguage) API which uses some datasouces for desambiguation.

The picture below shows the entities the subtypes and links to some of the data sources the service uses.
[image]

The Alchemy service offers Name Entity Recognition just like Relationship Extraction.

See the demo [here]: http://www.alchemyapi.com/products/demo/alchemylanguage

Comment: I actually want linguistic analysis features, specifically ones that understand the relationships of nouns with people and organizations which Relationship Extraction has. But I also want to be able to enhance the analysis engine's accuracy over time. What would you recommend?

Comment: I can't think on something that you can use Today without having to implement it. :(

Comment: I think it would be very useful if we could get the community to contribute to its accuracy. It really should be at the top of the list in terms of enhancements. Thanks @German Attanasio

Comment: The service is still in beta and your feedback is very valuable. I will pass it to the team involve in the new release

Answer (score 0):

Javier,

There are two aspects to answering your question.

1) If you are trying to make the Relationship Extraction work better in general (not with regard to a specific example), then we have a new offering coming up that does that. It's called Watson Knowledge Studio, and you can find more information at

http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/knowledge-studio.html

2) If you are trying to create individual feedback about specific examples. We are definitely considering adding such capability---not to the Relationship Extraction service, but to the Watson Knowledge Studio offering mentioned above, essentially for it to expose an API that collects such feedback and use it in model rebuilding.

Leiming